# Get the counts of the unique elements and their count in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have this vector lets say

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3]
```

How can I find the unique elements and their count something like this?

```
1 = 3
2 = 3
3 = 3
```

I can definitely loop over the individual elements and use some naive techniques. I don't want that kind of solution because my real data will be in the range of millions so I cannot just loop over each element.

What is the most efficient way to do it in matlab?

Comment: You had the term right there, UNIQUE - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Comment: @Divakar, unique will give me just [1;2;3] as result

Comment: Yes, I gave you pointer to explore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be hard to beat this for efficiency:

```
elements = unique(A);
counts = histc(A(:), elements);
```

Comment: It's not correct. numel(unique(A)) gave me 3. I want [3;3;3] because all the three elements were repeated three times

Comment: @Notlikethat Is that a challenge? :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Notlikethat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415959/2586922) is the way to go. But its efficiency (computation time) can actually be improved:

```
sA = sort([A(:); inf]); %// sort A
ind = diff(sA)~=0; %// index of last element of each run of equal values
elements = sA(ind); %// unique elements
counts = diff([0; find(ind)]); %// lengths of runs
```

**Benchmarking**:

```
clear all
A = randi(100,1e6,1); %// Example data. Large column vector

%// Notlikethat's answer
tic
elements = unique(A);
counts = histc(A(:), elements);
toc

clear elements counts

%// This answer
tic
sA = sort([A(:); inf]);
ind = diff(sA)~=0;
elements = sA(ind);
counts = diff([0; find(ind)]);
toc

Elapsed time is 0.175594 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.076032 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 Always believe that at low-level one can extract much more performance!